# C Writing into file stop working after use it as function?

Tags: c, file

I wrote a function that sets every number of a line in a .txt file to zero and clears the other file.

I originally wrote this logic in `main` and it worked perfectly fine. But now I need to make a menu for my program, so I need to put this logic into a function.

That's where the things go wrong. Once I move the logic into a function, it doesn't set the numbers to zero, it just clears the file, and I didn't changed anything.

### Expected result:

- Workers.txt : `Adam Washington Monday Friday --(use function)--> {clear}`
- days.txt: `1 0 0 0 1 0 0  --(use function)--> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

### Actual result:

It's clear in both files.

```
void ResetOwnData(){
        printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        FILE* freset = fopen ("workers.txt", "w");
        close(freset);
        FILE* freset2 = fopen ("days.txt", "w");
            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
                fprintf(freset2,"%d ",i+1);
            }
            fprintf(freset2,"\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
                fprintf(freset2,"%d ",0);
            }
        close(freset2);
        printf("Everything get reset!\n");
        printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: When you open a file with `fopen`, you need to close it with `fclose`, not with `close`.  You should have gotten a compiler warning about that, because `close` takes an `int` argument, not a `FILE *`.  Do you have warnings turned on?

Comment: It would also be smart to add some error checking so you know whether fopen succeeds or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main things that appear to be incorrect.

1. You are using `close` rather than `fclose`.  `fclose` is used with file streams (like you are using)
2. Your function is overwriting the one line that you want (e.g., `0 0 0 0 0 0 0`) with two lines because you have two `for` loops

[Here is a CodingGround link](http://%20http://tpcg.io/mZ3NN21L) to the corrections that I believe you are seeking.

You should add some error checking to ensure that you truly have opened the file and that you release any allocated memory